# Rule engine in KAA IOT

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, iot, kaa

How can I implement conditional rule engine in KAA server without integrating third party data analysis tool like Spark , Hadoop?
Is it possible to analyze and filter configuration/event schemas in server side and only send notification if condition matches?

I found some link regarding this problem but not the exact solution.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/kaaproject/rules%7Csort:relevance/kaaproject/B56e8Hsf_5I/FsWoSzTEFwAJ

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/kaaproject/rules/kaaproject/u5L8zEQvKNU/p-vKXuCLDgAJ

Comment: What type of notification do you want to send to endpoints? Do you mean (kaa notifications)[http://docs.kaaproject.org/display/KAA/Using+notifications]? You can filter your devices to (endpoint groups)[http://docs.kaaproject.org/display/KAA/Using+endpoint+groups] that can have different configurations and notification topics, what allows you to treat EP differently by condition matches.

Comment: I'm more concerned about dedicated rule engine rather than notification. it's like if the temperature exceeds 30 degrees, turn the led on or send an email. I don't know exactly but I think we need to have a controller to control and check conditions in server side. I know how is it done using configuration and events in client side but I'm trying to do that in server side, How could this condition be checked in server side? I'm from AWS IOT background so I'm searching similar rule engine here.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you can't check it on the server side. In the current version (0.9.0), there is no rule engine you are looking for. But one is planning to add such feature in release 1.0.0.

Comment: when will 1.0.0 release? right now M using 0.9.0, i want to trigger some action if certain conditions are met, what do u suggest?

Comment: Track [news](http://www.kaaproject.org/news/) about release 1.0.0. Today one is going to release 0.10.0 version and after that Kaa crew will start working on 1.0.0. Now you can use [REST log appender](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Programming-guide/Key-platform-features/Data-collection/Rest-log-appender/) and analyze data in your external system or create [custom log appender](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Customization-guide/Customizable-system-components/Log-appenders/) with necessary processing logic.